# Attach properties to functions within their definition

Tags: javascript

I want to achieve the same as this...

```
var x = function(){ return "abc"}
x.y = 123

x() // "abc"
x.y // 123
```

but to define the properties inside the function definition like this...

```
var x = function(){
    // declare `this.y` here somehow...
    // this.y = 123
    return "abc"
}
```

Comment: Be careful when you make examples with `this`... `this` only refers to the function itself if you explicitly call it as such (`func.call(func)`). An appropriate solution also depends on whether you have to set the `y` property (in your example) on each function call or only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give functions a name even when instantiating them as part of an expression:

```
var x = function x() {
  x.y = 123;
  return "abc";
}
```

Unfortunately, [some browsers have weird quirks](http://kangax.github.com/nfe/) in the implementation of that highly useful feature, so it's not really completely safe to use it.

Note that in the above, there are two separate "x" symbols. The function name "x" is bound inside the function, and it hides the variable "x" in the outer scope.